# Security Test and Monitoring for AWS EC2 running SFTP using OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, security, monitoring, sftp, network-monitoring

I have an EC2 Instance that is running SFTP via OpenSSH on Amazon Linux (CentOS). I'd like to run some tests to check for vulnerabilities that I'm not aware of, and I'd like to run monitoring software that watches for suspicious behavior. What is available / suggested? Free is great, but paying for a service is fine too.

**Some Notes**

- The only user able to connect over SSH is the ec2-user and that user is required to use a pem key
- Customers connecting to the system must have their IP whitelisted in the EC2's security group

**sshd_config Settings**

```
# SFTP Users
Match Group sftpusers
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -l DEBUG3 # -l INFO enables logging to /var/log/secure
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    X11Forwarding no

# SFTP Admins
Match Group sftpadmins
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -l DEBUG3 # -l INFO enables logging to /var/log/secure
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For monitoring of and notifications about vulnerable OS packages, you have the [AWS Inspector](https://aws.amazon.com/inspector/), which is dead-simple to get started with. For external vulnerability scanning, I'd recommend something like [OpenVAS](http://www.openvas.org/), which is also fairly easy to get started with.

Beyond those, you're looking at full-fledged intrusion detection/prevention systems, which are a completely different ball of wax, and can be quite complex to install and tune so that it gives good information.